# Uninstall a program installed with Wine

Tags: wine, uninstall

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. By using wine software i installed some software like nimbuzz and ibibo messenger. Both the programs are not working and showing the bug as `We're sorry, but an unknown error has caused ibibo Messenger to close.`

So I wanna uninstall those.

How to uninstall those type of programs which I installed through Wine?

Answer (score 365, accepted):

Type in a terminal or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `wine uninstaller` will give you access to the built in Add/Remove tool from `wine`. From there you can uninstall a program you have installed in a bottle.

To completely remove the bottle for your user (and thus remove everything from a wine bottle and start again) you can open a terminal and type `rm -rf ~/.wine` or as an alternative open Nautilus and in your home folder press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, locate the `.wine` folder and delete it. `wine` will create a new folder next time you try to use it.

Answer (score 27):

Search for `wine` in Dash. Select `Uninstall Wine software` there. There you can find all the softwares and will have option to uninstall.

[image: A screen shot of <code>Uninstall Wine software</code> option]

If you are using **Gnome Fallback** just go to Applications => Wine => Uninstall Wine software

Comment: Thanks souravc! Meanwhile I have managed to figure that out. Imagie that I was afraid that "Unistall Wine Software" will unistall Wine itself! :-)) That is why I did not used it from the very beginning. Anyway, I did encountered several small bugs in the process. I have shared my experience in detail in my answer and maybe you can help me into this.

Comment: souravc, I choose your answer as being the preferred one, because you mentioned Gnome Fallback. That's right, I don't use Unity, so your answer can be useful for users like me.

Comment: These shortcuts not longer show up in Unity after I've installed `wine-devel`.

Comment: @DanDascalescu try: `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/ wine syswow64/uninstaller.exe`

Answer (score 18):

Type "unistall wine software" in your dash and open the application.

[image: unistall wine software]

You will see the list of applications installed, click on the one you want to unistall and click on "Remove".

[image: remove installed application]

Comment: Thanks Jobin! It seems that you have answered while I was editing my own answer. Thank you! As you can see, I could figure out the solution but I have also found several bizarre behaviours. I have share my experience in details in my answer bellow. Maybe you could help me fix them.

Comment: In case, if someone doesn't find it in the dash, s/he can launch this uninstaller just by issuing `wine uninstaller` command from the terminal.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the answer! On the Wine menu, I clicked on "Uninstall Wine Software".

This opens an add/remove window. I just select the app and then click the "Modify/Remove" button.

[image: Removing a Windows program in Wine]

However, for some reasons that I can't understand, I have to do the same operation twice. After clicking OK three times, I still see the program on the list! When I select it and then click again on the "Modify/Remove" button I get this:

[image]

I click the "Yes" button and, finally, the app disappears from the list. But after that, I have to clean the shortcuts and folder manually. I wish I could find an easier and cleaner solution, but this one works fine anyway.

Comment: "On the Wine menu I clicked on "Unistall Wine Software""... strange I can't find any menu of Wine. Where is it?

Comment: @Marecky Enter command `wine uninstaller` from your terminal.