# How to uninstall a program in Wine?

Tags: wine, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Uninstall a program installed with Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101064/uninstall-a-program-installed-with-wine)

How do you uninstall a program in Wine? I tried installing a windows program through wine but it didn't work and now I can't figure our how to get rid of it.