# How do I uninstall Google Earth?

Tags: software-uninstall

I installed Google Earth on an older computer and discovered after I installed it that my graphics card will not support it.

I want to uninstall it but it does not appear in Ubuntu Software Center.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: did you install it using Wine?( windows version)

Comment: did you install it from a .deb package? (if you downloaded the linux version )

Comment: I installed it from a .deb package.

Comment: Follow the instructions i posted at my answer :)

Answer (score 8):

If you installed Google Earth with the .deb package from the web, you can use the same package with Ubuntu Software Centre to uninstall it. When you open again the package with the Software Centre you have the "uninstall" option instead of "install".

Also, you can use `sudo apt-get purge google-earth-stable` in terminal.

If you installed Google Earth via Wine, you can use the Wine uninstall app to uninstall it.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer solved your question, remember to put it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

- If you installed the **windows version** on your machine using  [wine](http://winehq.org) : 
  Type in a terminal or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `wine uninstaller` will give you access to the built in Add/Remove tool from `wine`. From there you can uninstall a program you have installed in a bottle.

  To completely remove the bottle for your user (and thus remove everything from a wine bottle and start again) you can open a terminal and type `rm -rf ~/.wine` or as an alternative open Nautilus and in your home folder press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, locate the `.wine` folder and delete it. `wine` will create a new folder next time you try to use it.

  (answered by Bruno Pereira at the question [uninstall a program installed with wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101064/uninstall-a-program-installed-with-wine#101075). )
  _____________________________________________
- if you installed the **linux version** on your machine (from the .deb package available at the google website) : 

  Open the synaptic package manager and search for the google maps package. Mark the package for  *complete removal* and select *apply*.

Comment: The package is now gone and I have a new and useful utility.  Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to mark the answer as 'accepted'.