# Google Earth uninstall

Tags: uninstall

- I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit
- I installed Google Earth using a 64-bit deb installation file.
- The program crashes at soon, just after the splash screen. Seems that it's a known issue. Message is [0525/102456:WARNING:sqlite_persistent_cookie_store.cc(504)] Cookie database version 0 is too old to handle.
- I decided to forget and uninstall it.
- I can't find it into the Ubuntu Software Centre. I used keyword "google", "google-earth", "earth" into the search box.
- I double clicked the deb file, and I can't get the "uninstall" button, just the "reinstall"  button.

Any hint? Maybe a way just using the terminal, and not the GUI?
THanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I uninstall Google Earth](http://askubuntu.com/questions/309902/how-do-i-uninstall-google-earth)

Answer (score 5):

Open terminal and type in:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-earth-stable
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Also, remember that you can reopen the same .deb file that you used to install said package, and it will open Software Center, and it should say "Uninstall" instead of the normal "Install".

Answer (score 2):

You can uninstall Google Earth as any other package. From the terminal you can do it using the following commands:

1- Find the exact package name:

```
dpkg --list 'google-earth*' | cat
```

which may show that the package name is google-earth-stable.

2- Uninstall the package:

```
sudo dpkg -P google-earth-stable
```

([Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleEarth)).

Comment: Would not recommend using dpkg, there's a reason that apt exists. Not safe. It's easier to break everything with dpkg.