# Unistalling Google Earth broke WIFI connection?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, software-uninstall

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

I had Google Earth installed on the machine.  I then installed Google Earth Pro-which never prompted me for a password and displayed a bunch of odd panels in weird places.  Assuming a conflict of software I uninstalled Google Earth using the instructions here: [Google Earth uninstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627926/google-earth-uninstall).

Oddly, the `gnome-terminal` package was removed from the computer, and the WiFi stopped working (although I can tether through my Android phone).  What happened?  Where is `gnome-terminal`, and why did my WiFi stop working?

Comment: What happened? You tell us... What were the packages removed by autoremove? You probably had severe issues with software sources before and that was the consequence.

Comment: Do you use to call gnome-terminal with Ctrl-Alt-T? Type ctrl-alt-F1, log on it, and type `which gnome-terminal`. It will tell you if and where it is.

Comment: Please see [Autoremove command removed too many packages](//askubuntu.com/q/540581) and review your bash history - you probably uninstalled something which many other packages depend on

Comment: I had gnome-terminal pinned to the desktop.  After it disappeared from there it was no longer openable using Ctrl-Alt-T, nor was it visible in the Dash or shown on the Ubuntu software center as an installed app.  Which Gnome terminal?   Terminal(gnome-terminal).

Comment: @Zanna I confirmed from the bash history that I only typed in sudo apt-get purge google-earth-stable and sudo apt-get autoremove.

Comment: hmmm, but *before* this session, did you run any remove commands without running `autoremove`? You can also take a look at `/var/log/apt/history.log` to see what was removed

Comment: @Zanna, No.  In fact, I was working in Google Earth right before this all happened, I had a WiFi connection-I was checking mail...no worries.  At this point I have the Terminal installed I just want to get my WiFi working again.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me - I mean, you ran some install command, and that marked various packages as un-needed, then when you ran `autoremove`, those packages were removed... Please check the log... try `grep gnome-terminal /var/log/apt/history.log` since it was probably on the same line

Comment: There is a lot I do not understand about Linux.  When I run `grep gnome-terminal /var/log/apt/history.log` the terminal returns `Remove:gnome-terminal:amd64 (3.18.3-1ubuntu1)` and then `Install:gnome-terminal:amd64 (3.18.3-1ubuntu1)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65193/discussion-between-zanna-and-gbg).