# how or where will i find C:\Program Files(x86) in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: find

How or where will I find C:\Program Files(x86) in Ubuntu 13.04?
I cannot find it. I need it as I have installed a game there and I need to uninstall it. I have already tried to post a similar question here but this was unclear. 
thanks

Comment: There is no C:\Program Files(x86) in Ubuntu.  How did you install the game, and how did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: thank you, I managed it finally, the wine was the key :). so there is this above mentioned file in ubuntu :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you used Wine?

Look here `~/.wine/drive_c/`
But I suggest using winecfg to uninstall.

Comment: i finally found it! thanks! but how is winecfg used? what should i do with this command?

Comment: It's a Wine GUI with configuration options, but also an add/remove program option. I haven't used it in some time, so It may not work as I remembered. If you using Ubuntu with Unity. Tap the Windows key, then type wine, you will probably see several Wine programs: "Configure Wine", "Uninstall Wine Software", etc. Try "Uninstall Wine Software".

Comment: ohh, i have already done the uninstallation thanks to this http://askubuntu.com/questions/101064/uninstall-a-program-installed-with-wine. great!

Answer (score 2):

For **PlayOnLinux**

```
cd /home/user/.PlayOnLinux
```

Then try to find destinations for **Program Files** folder

```
find . -type f -name "Program Files"
```

There may be many such folders depending on count of programs you installed

Answer (score 0):

If you have Wine installed then Wine will appear on your Menu.

Click on it and you will see, on the right panel of the menu, Browse C: Drive.

Click on that to see what is there.

You should immediately see Program Files(x86)

Comment: where is my Menu?

Comment: Hi, the Menu is located in the lower left hand corner of your screen if yopu have a bottom panel. If you have a top panel it should be visible there.

Comment: It should be in the right corner, a symbol sort of like the sun

Comment: As Kevin C Smith mentioned you can use Winecfg to remove the program but you can also just go through all the folders and delete everything related to the game but Winecfg is best.

Comment: i was not able to use winecfg, but i followed the advice in http://askubuntu.com/questions/101064/uninstall-a-program-installed-with-wine and typed "wine uninstaller" into terminal, and it worked! so the game is already uninstalled.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux directory structure is different from Windows's one. There is no "Program Files" directory.

For more info about the Linux directory structure, I found this usefull link on the internet, which may help you: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/09/linux-file-system-structure/

If the game you installed was a linux native game and you used a runnable file to install it (often .run/.bin, like most of the games from the Humble Bundle) they usually install themselves into the /opt directory.
If you used PlayOnLinux (or wine), you can find the wine "windows filesystem" in your home directory, inside the .wine directory ( ~/.wine/ ).

Instead, if you used the Ubuntu Software Center (or `apt-get`) to install the game, you can uninstall it by the USC or using

> sudo apt-get remove *GAMENAME*

Comment: thank you for your time. the wine software was the key :)