# Uninstall Spotify?

Tags: uninstall, spotify, software-uninstall

I was under the assumption it would work with wine, but was incorrect. I would like to completely remove it but everything I've seen on the internet hasn't helped in the slightest.

Comment: have you downloaded the linux or the windows version ?

Comment: windows, under the assumption it would work with wine

Comment: Wine comes with its own uninstaller ? There is a linux version but needs spotify premium http://askubuntu.com/questions/101064/uninstall-a-program-installed-with-wine

Comment: it does not list spotify

Comment: Is it defiantly installed ?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Well you said it didn't work, how do you know it's installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spotify no longer supports Wine (as of version 0.9.0, IIRC), so running the Windows client under Wine is guaranteed to result in pain. However, there is an official native client, download instructions are here:

https://www.spotify.com/us/download/previews/

I'm not sure why people still bother with using Wine for Spotify, I guess they just assume Spotify would never have a native Linux binary... but they do!

Edit: It should also be noted that one does *not* need Spotify Premium to run the native desktop client on Linux.