# How to uninstall a game which is not letting me uninstall it?

Tags: wine, uninstall, games

I had downloaded feist and installed it just to test the gaming capability of ubuntu, since am new to it.

Now as I can see it works perfectly fine, I am trying to uninstall it. But every time when I try to uninstall this game, I get an error message and it fails. Please help.

[image]

Comment: This is a Wine error.  It states that there is a memory sharing violation within the memory of that program's uninstaller in Wine.  There is no harm in letting it stay installed, though, why do you want to remove it?

Comment: First of all, thank you for instant response. I wasn't even expecting that kinda super fast support(No offense, am just new to linux) But yeah since I had installed it only for test purpose, I do not wish to keep it.

Comment: Any fix to this will be highly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Look at this - http://askubuntu.com/questions/101064/uninstall-a-program-installed-with-wine

Comment: Yep, that's what I did but It didn't work. So now do I need to uninstall wine gecko(32bit) to fix this problem?

Answer (score -2):

### Option 1

I can't say that this applies to Wine. This is a method of removing software that applies to Windows too (except paths and registry). If the provided uninstaller doesn't work anymore, all you have to do is manually check for:

- entries in `Program Files` folder: `~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/`. The folder you're interested in has usually the same name as the software you installed or the name of the developing company. Delete it.
- entries in `Application Data` folder: `~/.wine/drive_c/users/<your_name>/Application Data/`. Again, look for folders matching software name or developer company and delete them. You should also check the public application data folder at: `~/.wine/drive_c/users/Public/Application Data/`.
- registry entries. Wine stores registry data in three files: `~/.wine/system.reg`, `~/.wine/user.reg` and `~/.wine/userdef.reg`. Open each with a text editor and look for specific keys related to software or developer name and delete those keys.
- some software places files in `~/.wine/ProgramData` and/or `~/.wine/Windows`. Deleting folders in these places can break your current wineprefix, so you'll end up with Option 2.

### Option 2

Because that is a Windows application running in Wine, to completely remove it you can delete the current wineprefix

```
rm -rf ~/.wine
```

Note that after this, if you want to use Wine, you'll have to reconfigure it (i.e. install DLLs, runtimes and other software)

Comment: **That's using a cannon to kill a mosquito:** Yes, this will work, but also delete all settings of all installed applications in wine...  **:-(** -1

Comment: @Fabby and what do you propose? If the OP wanted only to try a Windows app, he should have made a special wineprefix, just like PlayOnLinux wants you to run each app in its own wineprefix to avoid this kind of situations.

Comment: Well, I'm also know as "Mr. Backup" around here and I regularly give answers that start with: "1. Restore your system backup" and then "2. in case you don't have one" and then normally come another 10 steps...  He could delete the specific directory containing the application and remove all references to the program from the registry, but that would be off-topic here...

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't expecting such a tremendous response to my question. Anyway, I accidently formatted my drive in which I had ubuntu. So I had to reinstall it and this solved my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: @Cornelius as the question is closed as a duplicate and the problem went away all by itself anyway: When I get answers that give me negative rep, I delete them and then the numbers get reversed by the system automatically...  **;-)**  If you disagree, drop me a comment @ Fabby...