# How to completely delete Steam (Windows Version) from Ubuntu

Tags: windows, wine, steam, versions

Pretty new to Ubuntu so excuse the novice question, but I just deleted the Wine installed Steam from Ubuntu using #wine uninstaller on terminal, but the logos did not disappear, just want to check in and make sure I didn't miss something... ps: I plan to reinstall this program later, would leaving any residual files cause any problems in the future??? I would also appreciate any tips due to my inexperience in this sort of thing... Edit:  Just to clarify I want to be sure I completely delete the application, as already mentioned, I used the uninstaller to "remove" the program, the problem is that there might still be residual files as the logos did not disappear, and every time I search steam I get two entries, one being Linux steam and the other being Windows steam (which shouldn't be on my computer anymore) it doesn't open but its still there and I would like to completely remove it from my machine, thanks in advance all... :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstall a program installed with Wine](http://askubuntu.com/questions/101064/uninstall-a-program-installed-with-wine)

Comment: As for the «residual files» — if you wanna be sure that everything is removed, just create new WINEPREFIX *(it is `~/.wine` by default)*. Everything left by installer being hosted there. The reason that you see the shortcut in the directory outside of the WINEPREFIX is simply that `~/.wine/drive_c/users/yourname/Desktop` is a symbolic link to `~/Desktop`. As for uninstallation, I think the pointed duplicate answers it. Actually, I think that the `wine uninstaller`, like the Windows one, just calls app's uninstaller, so there's a possibility that it would leave something. Not sure, though.