# problems removing wine

Tags: wine

i installed wine, and installed a program called autodesk meshmixer. I ran the windows installer for meshmixer in wine. when it installed, meshmixer made all of my .stl (3d mesh files) default to open with meshmixer, and made all of their icons into the meshmixer logo. i now want to completely remove wine and meshmixer, but i cant seem to do that. I deleted the ".wine" folder in /home/, and ran apt-get purge wine. this didnt work though, and all .stl files still try to open with wine. i want to completely remove wine from my computer, so it is exactly how it was before i installed wine. does wine and or the meshmixer program i installed resonate anywhere else on my computer?

Comment: you needed to uninstall meshmixer first. you have deleted the program but not the file associations or the short cuts created.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: See here:  [Uninstall a program installed with Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101064/uninstall-a-program-installed-with-wine) - or you can just change the file association - right clicking on an STL file > properties > open with and you can change it.

Comment: where else are there wine directories? ie what folder would i have to delete to remove ALL things related to wine?

Comment: i also need to remove wine, not just meshmixer

Comment: In addition to the duplicate , see man apt and review the difference between `apt remove` and `apt purge` http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt.8.html