# How To Uninstall Steam.exe?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I have the Windows version of Steam installed on my laptop...since it's a laptop I'll be wanting some of that space back, but I don't know how to uninstall a .exe file. I have the latest WINE-Staging installed and I'm running the latest Ubuntu 18.10.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you have the Windows version of Steam installed in Windows or in Ubuntu? In the latter case, you might want to check https://askubuntu.com/questions/101064/uninstall-a-program-installed-with-wine.

Comment: Yes, I am running it on Ubuntu 18.10, running Windows steam on Linux, and thank you the article did help