# How do I uninstall Putty (Windows application installed via Wine)?

Tags: 18.04, windows, wine

I've recently gotten to know Ubuntu 18.04, being very new to Linux. WINE has been one of the most useful tools I've also come across because now I can use my Windows applications on my Linux platform.

But how do I uninstall those Windows applications, such as Putty? It's not a snap so I can't remove it via the Ubuntu Software application, neither is there a clear way via the terminal to do it since I assume the files will be saved under a different repository being a Windows application originally.

Answer (score 0):

It is already answered multiple times. Because of too less reputation I am not allowed to write it a s a comment.

[alt]+[F2] -> wine unsinstaller -> Follow the Add/Remove dialog.

[Uninstall a program installed with Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101064/uninstall-a-program-installed-with-wine)

Comment: Thanks alot! This was exactly what I was hoping for. I hope this post can be used to link to the original question. The only thing that I can't seem to remove still are the icons relating to Putty on Show Applications.